# whether the product of two symmetric matrix with one positive definite is diagonizable

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, numerical-linear-algebra

Assume $A$ is symmetric and positive definite, $B$ is symmetric.

Proof that $AB$ is diagonalizable and all the eigenvalues are real.

I think it is better to write $A=R^TR$ and $B=XDX^{-1}$, but I still cannot obtain a diagonalization form.

Any ideas?

Many thanks

Answer (score 2):

Hopefully I didn't do any mistakes:

You can write $B= PDP^T$ with $PP^T=P^TP=I$.

Then 
$$AB= R^TRPDP^T=R^T \bigl( RP D (RP)^T \bigr) (R^T)^{-1}$$

Now use the fact that $ RP D (RP)^T$ is symmetric, thus diagonalizable.

Comment: Hi, OK, thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

One approach is to note that
$$
A^{-1/2}(AB)A^{1/2} = A^{1/2}BA^{1/2}
$$
So, $AB$ is similar to a symmetric matrix.

Comment: OK, thanks a quite a lot !